# Regular Expressions: /(\d*)/(\d*)/(.*[0-9a-zA-Z]) EXCEPT "page"

Tags: regex, wordpress

I want to redirect all the URLs which are like this:

```
olivian.ro/[year between 1997 & 2050]/[month between 01 & 12]/anything-starting-with-an-alphanumeric
```

except for

```
olivian.ro/[year between 1997 & 2050]/page/whatever.
```

This condition currently does well at redirecting things.

```
/(\d*)/(\d*)/(.*[0-9a-zA-Z])
```

The problem is with adding an exception to the third volume.

So, how do I add, using a regular expression, to this:

```
(.*[0-9a-zA-Z])
```

the rule *except for the situation in which this is "page"*

I want `olivian.ro/2012/09/my-article-about-scissors` redirecting to `olivian.ro/my-article-about-scissors`

but I don't want `olivian.ro/2012/09/page/2` redirecting to `olivian.ro/page/2`

I am using the redirection plugin for WordPress, which redirects the first set of rules, to `/$3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In .htaccess, add this before your `RewriteRule`:

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/\d+/\d+/page/
```

In php itself, you can do it in the regex itself with a negative lookahead:

```
#/(\d*)/(\d*)/(?!page)(.*[0-9a-z])#i
```

Note that `(.*[0-9a-z])` means *"any character (.) one or more times, and after that 1 character in 0-9 or a-z"*, which I doubt is what you want... `([0-9a-z]*)` seems more apt, or even `([^/]+)` (anything but a slash, at least one). Your actually description of it (*"anything-starting-with-an-alphanumeric"*) would of course be `([0-9a-zA-Z].*)`

Comment: Wrikken,

I needed the regex. Thank you so much for the kind reply.

This worked perfectly:
"#/(\d*)/(\d*)/(?!page)(.*[0-9a-z])#i"

I described poorly something which I didn't understand correctly myself, it was taken from the Internet. :)

Thanks!

I can't vote, I would vote you.